# Executing MySQL query in shell

Tags: mysql, shell

I am trying to create an easy to use script for replacing outdated URL's in a WordPress db, however, it seems there is something off in my script.

This gets the old and new url

```
echo "\nPlease enter the OLD url(EXAMPLE http://www.oldurl.com/ ): "
read oUrl
echo "\nPlease enter the NEW url(EXAMPLE http://www.newurl.com/ ): "
read nUrl
```

This is the query call

```
mysql -u $user -p$passwd -h $host $dbName -Bse \
"USE $dbName; 
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, '$oUrl', '$nUrl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, '$oUrl', '$nUrl');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content '$oUrl', '$nUrl');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '$oUrl', '$nUrl');"
```

This is the error I am seeing.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
>   syntax to use near ''http://www.oldurl.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com/')' at line 1

It is my understanding that this should be pretty straight forward but something is causing the script to escape it seems but I am not sure what.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to print out the constructed query so that you can inspect it and see where the problem is, you can replace `mysql ....` with `printf '%s\n' ...`

Comment: If that is your exact error, it doesn't look like it's being escaped. I would agree that printing our the SQL generated would be a good start here. There is nothing obviously wrong with the way you are doing this.

Comment: Well, I tried to output to an SQL file and execute that and it didn't work and the SQL looked correct. Also I had it set to print on the terminal and it looks good to me:

Comment: USE somedb;
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com/');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content 'http://www.oldurl.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com/');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.oldurl.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com/');

Comment: There's an extra semicolon at the end of `replace(option_value, 'oldurl.com/';,`

Comment: Where is that semicolon coming from? ***Every*** time you have `'oldurl.com/'` it's followed by a semicolon. If I set these variables myself on my own system and printf your statement, I don't get those... is there something you aren't sharing?

Comment: Using a here-doc would be easier than a multi-line string like this.

Comment: You don't need `USE $dbName;`, that's done automatically by specifying the dbname as the argument.

Comment: You don't need two `UPDATE wp_posts` statements, you can set both columns in one statement.

Comment: The error you're getting would happen if you left out one of the quotes before `$oUrl`, or if the user typed a quote at the beginning of the old URL.

Comment: I'm not sure where those semicolons are coming from. They aren't there in the terminal only when I paste it to the comment box.

Comment: I've found the error, it was this line 
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content 'http://www.someoldurl.com/', 'http://www.newurl.com/');

It was missing a comma after post_content.  Thank you everyone for the ideas and help